# Adding node to existing xml element

Tags: c#, xml, nullreferenceexception

I'm getting this error when trying to append a node to existing element in my xml document.The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
<houses>
  <house windowsc="three">
    <wind>0</wind>
    <windows>
    </windows>
  </house>
</houses>
```

Code:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

xDoc.Load("C:\\Houseplans.xml");

XmlElement xhousing = xDoc.DocumentElement["houses/house[@windowsc=\"three\"]/windows"];
XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
xName.InnerText = "hi";
xhousing.AppendChild(xName);
```

Comment: What did the debugger say?

Comment: Can you use LINQ to XML?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: your `xhousing is null`, your xpath isn't getting the node

Comment: @Josh looks like `xhousing` is `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use SelectSingleNode:

```
XmlNode xhousing = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(@"//house[@windowsc='three']/windows");
XmlNode xName = xDoc.CreateElement("Name");
xName.InnerText = "hi";
xhousing.AppendChild(xName);
```

Comment: Note that //house is different to /houses/house.